# How do I initialize this custom class that inherits from UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to initialize this custom class, the code isn't mine and I'm fairly new to Obj-C, so I'm slow on the uptake.

PFTintedButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class CALayer;

typedef enum
{
    PFTintedButtonRenderTypeStandard,
    PFTintedButtonRenderTypeCandy,
    PFTintedButtonRenderTypeOpal,
} PFTintedButtonRenderType;


@interface PFTintedButton : UIButton
{
@private
    UIColor * tint;
    CGFloat cornerRadius;
    PFTintedButtonRenderType renderType;

    UIImage * stretchImage;
    CALayer * glowLayer;

    UILabel * subLabel;

    BOOL customShadow;
    BOOL customTitleColor;
}

@property( nonatomic, retain ) UIColor * tint;
@property( nonatomic, assign ) CGFloat cornerRadius;
@property( nonatomic, assign ) PFTintedButtonRenderType renderType;
@property( nonatomic, readonly ) UILabel * subLabel;



@end
```

PFTintedButton.m excerpt

```
#import "PFTintedButton.h"
#import "PFDrawTools.h"
#import "UIColor+PFExtensions.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define glowRadius      30

@interface PFTintedButton()
-(void) createBackgroundImage;
-(void) createGlowLayer;
@end


@implementation PFTintedButton

-(void) dealloc 
{
    SafeRelease( tint );
    SafeRelease( stretchImage );
    SafeRelease( subLabel );
    SafeRelease( glowLayer );

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: self selector: @selector(createGlowLayer) object: nil];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: self selector: @selector(renderGlowLayerOnMainThread) object: nil];

    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) initCommon
{
    cornerRadius = 6;
}

-(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame 
{
    if( self = [super initWithFrame: frame] ) 
    {
        [self initCommon];
    }

    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) coder 
{
    if( self = [super initWithCoder: coder] ) 
    {
        // this is such a hack but there's no other way to determine if the title label's settings
        // have been modified in IB.
        NSDictionary * dic = [coder decodeObjectForKey: @"UIButtonStatefulContent"];
        NSObject * st = [dic objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: UIControlStateNormal]];
        NSString * bc = [st description];

        customTitleColor = [bc rangeOfString: @"TitleColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.196078 0.309804 0.521569 1"].location == NSNotFound;
        customShadow = [bc rangeOfString: @"ShadowColor = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.5 0.5 0.5 1"].location == NSNotFound;

        [self initCommon];

        //[super setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: .5]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

I just included a small bit of the implementation, [the full source can be found here.](https://raw.github.com/appsinyourpants/Pants-Framework/master/Classes/Views/PFTintedButton.m) [As a part of this repository](https://github.com/appsinyourpants/Pants-Framework) by [Paul-Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76456/paul-alexander).

I initialize it like this:

```
PFTintedButton* buttony = [PFTintedButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttony setTint:[UIColor redColor]];
[buttony setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[buttony setRenderType:PFTintedButtonRenderTypeCandy];
[buttony setTitle:@"Title for Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And it hiccups in PFDrawTools, it seems the tint variable is nil. So is it because I am initializing it incorrectly? Has anyone had success with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to explicitly handle initWithFrame, I would try that.

```
PFTintedButton *buttony = [[[PFTintedButton alloc] initWithFrame:<some_frame>] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
PFTintedButton* buttony = [[PFTintedButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `buttonWithType:` initialize method in `PFTintedButton` class?